# mismatch in formal parameter list

Tags: c++, function, parameters

> \a3.cpp(75): error C2563: mismatch in formal parameter list

I'm certain I'm passing the function checkout with 3 doubles, I don't know why I'm getting the error I am. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

 const double peanut_PRICE = 1.80;
 const double peanut_SHIP = 0.50;
 const double BOOK_PRICE = 9;
 const double BOOK_SHIP = 1.06;
 const double MOVIE_PRICE = 13.99;
 const double MOVIE_SHIP = 0.05;

 double checkout (double myamountofbooks, double myamountofmovies, double mypoundsofpeanuts)
 {
  myamountofbooks = myamountofbooks * (BOOK_PRICE + BOOK_SHIP);
  myamountofmovies = myamountofmovies * MOVIE_PRICE * (1 + MOVIE_SHIP);
  mypoundsofpeanuts = mypoundsofpeanuts * (peanut_PRICE + peanut_SHIP);
  return (myamountofbooks + myamountofmovies + mypoundsofpeanuts);

 }

 bool validUserImput (int whereUserWantsToGoNext)
 {

  if (whereUserWantsToGoNext > 50 || whereUserWantsToGoNext < 0)
   return false;
  else return true;

 }

 bool validUserImput (double whereUserWantsToGoNext)
 {

  if (whereUserWantsToGoNext > 50 || whereUserWantsToGoNext < 0)
   return false;
  else return true;

 }

int main()
{
 //===========================Declaration Statements==================================
 double amountofbooks = 0;
 double amountofmovies = 0;
 double poundsofpeanuts = 0;
 int whereUserWantsToGoNext = 0;


  while (! (whereUserWantsToGoNext == 4) ) 
  {
   cout << "1. Books\n2. Peanuts\n3. Movies\n4. Checkout\n" << endl;
   cin >> whereUserWantsToGoNext; 
   if (!validUserImput(whereUserWantsToGoNext)) cout << "INVALID IMPUT" << endl;

   if (whereUserWantsToGoNext == 1){
    cout << "Please enter your number of books";
    cin >> amountofbooks;
    if (!validUserImput(amountofbooks)) cout << "INVALID IMPUT" << endl;
   }

   if (whereUserWantsToGoNext == 3){
    cout << "Now please enter the number of movies you've selected";
    cin >> amountofmovies; 
    if (!validUserImput(amountofmovies)) cout << "INVALID IMPUT" << endl;
   }

   if (whereUserWantsToGoNext == 2) {
    cout << "Please enter the weight(in pounds) of your peanuts";
    cin >> poundsofpeanuts;
    if (!validUserImput(poundsofpeanuts)) cout << "INVALID IMPUT" << endl;
   }
   if (validUserImput == 4) cout << "Total Cost is..." << checkout(amountofbooks, amountofmovies, poundsofpeanuts);
  }
 cin >> amountofbooks;
 }
```

Comment: The word is "input", as in input/output.

Comment: Your problem is pretty much copy/paste errors on the last part where you try to checkout.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
if (validUserImput == 4) ...
```

`validUserImput` is a function, but you are not calling that function, you are trying to compare it to `4`.

If you wanted to keep track of the number of valid inputs you received, you could instead add a new variable that you manually increment on every valid input.

Answer (score 2):

The last if - you are comparing function pointer to an integer. try this:

```
if (validUserImput(3) == 4) cout << "Total Cost is..." << checkout(amountofbooks, amountofmovies, poundsofpeanuts);
```

Comment: `validUserImput` returns a boolean

Comment: @Charles Salvia validUserImput is a function that takes int as an argumentm and returns a bool. If you call it like it is called in the example, it is a function pointer of type bool (*)(int), not a call to the function validUserImput

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to display the result of the `checkout` function if the user selects `4`.  So you probably wanted to write:

```
   if (whereUserWantsToGoNext == 4) cout << "Total Cost is..." << checkout(amountofbooks, amountofmovies, poundsofpeanuts) << endl;
```